# Get first date of current year in Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

How do I go about getting the first date of current year using Redshift?

I am familiar with T-SQL/SQL in SSMS but I am not entirely sure how to do this in Redshift.

In SSMS I would have done:

```
SELECT
   DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS StartOfYear
```

However, some of the functions were not working using Amazon Redshift.

Comment: Have you tried: `(date_part('year', now())::text || '-01-01')::date` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`DATE_TRUNC`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATE_TRUNC.html) with `year` param will do this.

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('year', TIMESTAMP '20200430 04:05:06.789');
```

---

**OUTPUT**

| date_trunc |
| --- |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00 |

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone needs it dynamically without explicitly specifying the date it can be done this way:

```
 CAST(DATE_TRUNC('year', current_date) AS DATE)
```